# How do I show percentage in a Libreoffice columns chart from fraction data?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I would like to know if there is a way to create a chart in Libreoffice Calc where I get percentage values on the chart from fractions.
Example:

```
Group 1     4/10    6/10
Group 2     5/10    5/10
```

I would like the chart to show the first column not like 4/10 but like 40% and so on.
Thanks